# php sql запрос на выборку столбцов кроме одного

Tags: php, mysql, sql, запрос

```
[![$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `for_user_id` = '$user_id' AND 
`date` = '$date'") or die(mysql_errno());
```

Подскажите как можно выбрать из таблицы все столбцы кроме одного не используя перечисления столбцов (так как их может быть много).
То есть мне в массив должны попасть данные из всех столбцов, для всех пользователей кроме User_ID][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIAty.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIAty.png)

Comment: SELECT ('for_user_id', 'date') FROM `tasks` WHERE `for_user_id` = '$user_id' AND 
`date` = '$date'

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: http://sql-ex.ru/help/select20.php